# How could I convert a sequence of Listnode into 2 seperate lists

Tags: c#, linked-list

I have a sequence of listnode objects

list -> [1] -> [2] -> [3] -> [4] /

and I need to convert it into 2 separate lists.

list -> [4] -> [2] /
list2 -> [3} -> [1] /

I'm not even sure where I'd begin with this one. I've been playing around with my_list.AddLast() and my_list.Remove() but am not sure what I'd do in order to create that one list into 2, and then move the numbers around as indicated.

Comment: How is your list declared? The typical `List<T>` doesn't exposed anything like a _"listnode"_. If it is a normal list, convert it to an array (`.ToArray`) and the iterate backwards over the array, sticking the even numbered entries in one list and the odd on another.

Comment: You should provide a minimum and complete reproducible example and also try to be more specific about your question. Do you want a specific or random split and order?

Comment: I was looking for the specefic split/order as above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer based on my comment above.  I take your input, convert it to an array, and then iterate over the array backwards (from the end to the beginning).  I put the odd numbered items in the array into one list and the even-numbered ones in another.  Then I return the two lists as a tuple:

```
private (List<T>, List<T>) SplitList<T>(IEnumerable<T> input)
{
    var asArray = input.ToArray();
    var evens = new List<T>();
    var odds = new List<T>();
    for (var i = asArray.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)     //if even
        {
            evens.Add(asArray[i]);
        }
        else
        {
             odds.Add(asArray[i]);   
        }
    }

    return (evens, odds);
}
```

Once that's done, it's easily callable.  This will work with your 4-valued example, but it will also work with any number of things of any type.  I'm using a range of integers to make my point clear, but it should work with just about anything.

```
 var oneToFour = Enumerable.Range(1, 4);
 var result = SplitList(oneToFour);
 var oneToFifteen = Enumerable.Range(1, 15);
 var other = SplitList(oneToFifteen);
```

Some people may say "Why not just index over the list backwards".  Yes, `List<T>` is implemented internally with an array and is indexable.  But, in my mind, a List is `O(N)` for indexing (rather than `O(1)` like an array); that it's indexable is simply an implementation detail.